# Must I use Shim in RequireJS for all non-AMD js lib in an app?

Tags: jquery-plugins, requirejs

Right now our app has scripts that are loaded the old fashion way and a part of the app are all RequireJS & Backbone views/models.  We are having some RequireJS script loading error on live (through frontend onError collection via ajax) which are not reproducible in dev.

We suspect it's the way some scripts are loaded in the old fashion way while the others are using shim and requireJS.  Could this be the problem?  What shall one do?  Shall we add every non-AMD JS files (e.g. jquery plugins) into Shim?

What would be the benefit of loading everything in Shim?  I can see many of our old script will need to be modified to require certain scripts from RequireJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use shims only for non-AMD code *that you want to load with RequireJS*. It is quite fine to load non-AMD code using `<script>` tags, so long as you don't expect RequireJS to recognize this code as a module. I've actually done it. No problem whatsoever.

> What would be the benefit of loading everything in Shim?

The answer to this depends on the specific of your application and the specifics of what you want to load. In my applications there would be absolutely no benefit whatsoever to loading every single piece of non-AMD code using shims.

Comment: would RequireJS somehow loads Before the regular non-AMD code loaded using `<script>`?  Even if we added the script tag in `<head>` before requireJS's?

Comment: Unless you explicitly specify the `async` attribute on `<script>` scripts load and execute in the order they appear in the HTML.

Comment: Thanks, just as I thought, but I just couldn't figure out why are there so many loading errors on live.  Must I use R for production?

Comment: (Assuming R === RequireJS.) If you used RequireJS for development, I don't know how production could run without it. There's [almond](https://github.com/jrburke/almond) which one could argue is not "RequireJS" properly speaking, but I doubt it would make a difference in what you are reporting here. Problems like what you are reporting are usually due to some dependency having been missed somewhere along the line. Timing differences between dev and production cause the missing dependency to become a problem only in dev or only in production. (I've seen both.)

Comment: I meant R.js the optimizer.  We have not combined all the JS files into 1 file.  I wonder if that'd solve the loading problem.

Comment: Using `r.js` may make the errors disappear. Without having first pinpointed the problem and found that using `r.js` is the solution, I'd be concerned about just *masking* the problem rather than *fixing* it.

Comment: What do you purpose for fixing it the right way?  We even tried slowing down the network with Charles in exactly the same version of Firefox and just couldn't reproduce the random script loading error caught in RequireJS's onError.

Answer (score 0):

If your library is 1) not AMD and 2) attaches to window, you can pull that library in using requirejs and just not expect to use its export.

So, for instance, the latest jquery attaches to the window.  Lets pretend that is isn't already AMD compliant.

```
define(['someview', 'jquery'], function(someview) {
  $('body').append(someview());
});
```

requirejs will load jquery and evaluate it before executing the callback.  The fact that it is not AMD compliant is irrelevant. This is very appropriate and I think it is more appropriate than putting script tags in your page.  Your code should declare all of its dependencies whether those dependencies export or are AMD compliant or not.  Just put them as the last entries in the dependencies array.